# Как определить платформу (операционную систему) на которой работает приложение, написанное на Dart'e

Tags: flutter, dart

При разработке кроссплатформенных приложений периодически приходится учитывать особенности платформы, на которой приложение должно работать. В частности принципы построения пользовательского интерфейса на **Android** и **iOS** заметно отличаются и было бы желательно чтобы приложение предлагало тот же пользовательский опыт, что и нативные приложения, написанные под эту платформу с учетом тех принципов, которые декларируются разработчиками данной системы.

**Отсюда вопрос:**
Есть ли возможность узнать на какой платформе работает приложение и как это сделать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Определение текущей платформы

Да, это возможно сделать с помощью класса `Platform` из пакета `dart:io`

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // код, предназначенный для Android
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // код, предназначенный для iOS
}
```

Помимо Android, iOS данный пакет также может определить Linux, Windows, MacOS, Fuchsia

- `Platform.isAndroid`
- `Platform.isFuchsia`
- `Platform.isIOS`
- `Platform.isLinux`
- `Platform.isMacOS`
- `Platform.isWindows`

#### Определение того, работает ли приложение в веб-браузере

Также если Вы разрабатываете кроссплатформенное приложение на `Flutter`'е, которое может запускаться как на мобильных устройствах, десктопе, **так и в браузере** - вам нужен будет способ определить скомпилировано ли данное приложение под веб или нет.

Для этого есть константа `kIsWeb` в пакете `package:flutter/foundation.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // запущено в вебе
} else {
  // это точно не веб. Тут нужно сделать еще пару проверок, описанных выше
}
```

---

**Документация:**

- `Platform`:
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html
- `kIsWeb`:
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/4558866